# Lookup multiple values in a single cell (separated by commas) and then return the values to a single cell (also comma separated)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I need to Vlookup on column A of sheet1 with cell A1, A2 values

```
SD-121, SD-232, SD-23
SD-323,SD-333
```

and so on..
vLookup table in a different sheet with column A, B, C, D. Column A having

```
A            B
SD-232      US
SD-23       UK
SD-323      IN
SD-333      SG
SD-121      CN
```

The lookup result is to be displayed in Column B of sheet1 result cell B1 and B2

```
B
CN, US, UK
IN, SG
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve. Try to provide an example and expected result, so others will understand you.

Comment: @tarashpka check if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user function to loop the values through the VLOOKUP function:

```
Function VLOOKUPARRAY(ByVal lookup_val As Range, ByVal table_array As Range, ByVal col_index_num As Integer, Optional ByVal range_lookup As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim a1() As String
    Dim a2() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'Recalculate whenever a calculation happens on the worksheet
    Application.Volatile

    'Get the lookup value from the cell
    s = lookup_val.Value
    'Split into array
    a1 = Split(s, ",")
    'Set output array to input array dimensions
    ReDim a2(0 To UBound(a1))
    'Loop through input array and set output array elements to lookup results using application lookup function.
    For i = 0 To UBound(a1)
        a2(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Trim(a1(i)), table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)
    Next i
    'Loop through output array and load values into a string
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(a2)
        s = s & a2(i) & ", "
    Next i
    'Knock the final ", " off the end of the string
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(", "))
    'Set function output to string value.
    VLOOKUPARRAY = s
End Function
```

That was quick and dirty, but it gave me the desired output. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 latest update from Feb 2016 then you can use the following array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,A1)),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,""))
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The return will be in order of the list on sheet 2, not the order of the comma delimited string.

[image]

Comment: I do not have latest Office 365. Still thanks for response