# How can I perform a vlookup against a variable length comma separated column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vlookup

I have a large csv extract with a comma separated column containing "tags."  The tags can be names, numbers, labels or a combination of those.  I need to identify all 6-digit numeric strings in the cell, then perform a standard vlookup each one against each and return a comma separated list.  The data in the cell is all comma separated, and all ID's are 6-digit.

I have tried un-comma-separating the column, but it's unwieldy.  Search, Find, sumproduct, vlookup do not work in isolation, I believe VBA is required.

One the surface, the below article is identical to my need, however it produces #VALUE anytime a numeric string is introduced, and I'm not well-versed in VBA to be able to debug it - 
[Lookup multiple values in a single cell (separated by commas) and then return the values to a single cell (also comma separated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942740/lookup-multiple-values-in-a-single-cell-separated-by-commas-and-then-return-th)

Credit to @JMcD for the following code -

```
Function VLOOKUPARRAY(ByVal lookup_val As Range, ByVal table_array As Range, ByVal col_index_num As Integer, Optional ByVal range_lookup As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim a1() As String
    Dim a2() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'Recalculate whenever a calculation happens on the worksheet
    Application.Volatile

    'Get the lookup value from the cell
    s = lookup_val.Value
    'Split into array
    a1 = Split(s, ",")
    'Set output array to input array dimensions
    ReDim a2(0 To UBound(a1))
    'Loop through input array and set output array elements to lookup results using application lookup function.
    For i = 0 To UBound(a1)
        a2(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Trim(a1(i)), table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)
    Next i
    'Loop through output array and load values into a string
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(a2)
        s = s & a2(i) & ", "
    Next i
    'Knock the final ", " off the end of the string
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(", "))
    'Set function output to string value.
    VLOOKUPARRAY = s
End Function
```

Tags

```
10000
10002, Baseball, Fireworks, 10001, 1000-ERT
Test, Howdy, 10000, Middle check
Doublecheck, 10000, Laptop 10002
Test blank case, 8675309, It's in the middle
```

Tag Team

```
10000   Team1
10001   Team2
10002   Team1
10003   Team2
```

I would like this to return -

```
Team1
Team1, Team2
Team1
Team1
Team1, Team1
NULL, #N/A, 0 - Doesn't matter much what this returns as long as it doesn't interrupt the script.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel or latter then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1:$F$4,A1)),$G$1:$G$4,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365 Excel then put this in a module:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

And use the function as described above.